# understanding sup notation

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

From the book, Probability and Measure, Billingsley, 3rd, I have problems understanding Eq. 6.6, Page 88:

$$P(\sup_k N_k \leq x ) \leq P(N_n \leq x)$$

where $N_n=1_{A_n}$ and $A_n$ is an iid sequence of events.

More specifically, I have problems with $(\sup_k N_k \leq x )$. I understand that it can be written as $$\{\sup_k N_k \leq x\} = \{\omega : \sup_k N_k(\omega) \leq x\},$$
and I know the definition $$\lim \sup_n (A_n \leq x) = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_k \leq x ),$$
but I don't know how to interpret $(\sup_k N_k \leq x )$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's $(\sup_kN_k)\leq x$, not $\sup_k(N_k\leq x)$.

Comment: from the book, the inequality is $P(\sup_k N_k \leq x ) \leq P(N_n \leq x)$

Comment: Yes, and I was telling you what the left side of that inequality means. You said you don't know how to interpret $(\sup_kN_k\leq x)$ and the previous line(about $\limsup$) suggested that you were thinking in terms of the sup of some events, whereas the intended meaning is about the sup of some random variables $N_k$.